# If Statements Order

Tags: python, operator-precedence

I was doing some of the CodingBat exercises using Python until I stumbled upon a problem with my proposed solution.

The link for the exercise is [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p119867)

I tried solving it using this code:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
    if vacation and day == 0 or day == 6:
        return "off"
    elif vacation and day != 0 and day != 6:
        return "10:00"
    if vacation == False and day == 0 or day == 6:
        return "10:00"
    elif vacation == False and day != 0 or day != 6:
        return "7:00"
```

What happens is that when day is 6 and vacations is False, it returns "off" instead of "10:00". Can you share some light here? Is one of the former If statements evaluating to the "10:00" value?

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't be using `vacation == False`; just use `not vacation`. (There are some people who argue that `== False` is good, but (a) they're wrong, (b) they would want you to use `vacation == True` rather than just `vacation` in the other two cases, and (c) they're wrong. :))

Comment: Also, this might be easier to think about with nested statements. First, `if vacation:` … `else:`. Then, inside each of those, `if day == 0 or day == 6:` … `else:`. It means 10 lines of code instead of 8, but they're shorter lines, and more obvious, and harder to get wrong (in particular, your error could never come up that way).

Comment: Or, alternatively, do `weekday = day == 0 or day == 6`, then you can write `vacation and weekday`, `vacation and not weekday`, `not vacation and weekday`, `not vacation and not weekday`, which is probably even _more_ readable.

Answer (score 3):

Others already pointed out the precedence of the logical operators. Maybe you might consider refactoring your conditions somewhat like this (which IMHO reflects more nicely the decision tree):

```
if vacation:
    if day == 0 or day == 6: #or if day in (0, 6)
         return "off"
    else:
         return "10:00"
else:
     if day == 0 or day == 6: #or if day in (0, 6)
         return "10:00"
     else:
         return "7:00"
```

Elaborating dimo414's comment:

```
weekend = day in (0, 6)
if vacation:
    if weekend:
         return "off"
    else:
         return "10:00"
else:
     if weekend:
         return "10:00"
     else:
         return "7:00"
```

Or even:

```
weekend = day in (0, 6)
if vacation:
    return "off" if weekend else "10:00"
else:
    return "10:00" if weekend else "7:00"
```

Comment: Even better, store the `(0, 6)` tuple in a variable, then you can say `day in weekend` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
vacation and day == 0 or day == 6
```

evaluates like

```
(vacation and day == 0) or day == 6
```

So if `day == 6` your then clause evaluates.

You may want instead

```
vacation and (day == 0 or day == 6)
```

Comment: Why did I always think it was the complete opposite...
Anywyas, thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: @user3124364: Because anyone who reads "higher precedence" or "more bound" or almost any other description in the docs of any language has no idea which direction that actually means. If you write a parser, or get bitten by this bug enough times in your life, eventually it will become obvious to you, and you too can write docs that confuse novices. :)

Answer (score 0):

The priority of logical `or` is lower than the priority of `and` in Python

So in the line here

```
 if vacation and day == 0 or day == 6:
```

as long as `day == 6`, the whole statement would be true.

So the correct one would be

```
 if vacation and (day == 0 or day == 6):
```

Comment: Technically they are logical operators, not bitwise.

Comment: @AlbusShin: It's not fixed; you're still talking about "bitwise and".

Answer (score 0):

**`and`** takes precedense to **`or`**.
So change:

```
if vacation and day == 0 or day == 6:
```

with

```
if vacation and (day == 0 or day == 6):
```

or better and more english like:

```
if vacation and day in [0, 6]:
```

So I'd make it look like this to be more readable

```
weekend = [0, 6]
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if vacation:
    return day in weekend and "off" or "10:00"
  else:
    return day in weekend and "10:00" or "7:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the clearest solution here is to just name your intermediate values:

```
weekend = day == 0 or day == 6
```

Now, whether you leave things structured as-is:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
     if vacation and weekend:
         return "off"
     elif vacation and weekday:
         return "10:00"
     elif not vacation and weekend:
         return "10:00"
     elif not vacation and not weekend:
         return "7:00"
```

… or refactor it into nested `if` statements:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
     if vacation:
         if weekend:
             return "off"
         else:
             return "10:00"
     else:
         if weekend:
             return "10:00"
         else:
             return "7:00"
```

… or refactor it at a higher logical level:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
     if vacation and weekend:
         return "off"
     elif vacation or weekend:
         return "10:00"
     else:
         return "7:00"
```

… it's immediately obvious what's going on, and this problem couldn't even arise in the first place.

It also avoids another very common bug, where people de-morgan the combination of `not` with `and` or `or` only half-way, and you end up with things like `not a and b` when you meant `not a and not b`.

And it makes your code more robust to expansion—if you later decide to, e.g., run your code in a country that starts numbering weeks from Monday instead of Sunday, you only have to change one line of code instead of four different lines (and four lines is almost enough to guarantee that you'll get one of them wrong…).

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I (very personally) don't find very convenient is you last code snippet. When you have 4 cases (weekend or not, vacation or not), I prefer to write out all four cases, even if two of them result in the same value (Or n cases with m results). The problem is that the `elif` is a hidden `not (vacation and weekend) and (vacation or weekend)` which is not very easy to read (and as they say, code is read more often than written). Especially the "immediatly obvious" part crosses the Hades here.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: My point is that, if you use a nicely-named variable instead of copying and pasting the condition, no matter how you structure the `if`s, there's no way to get the conditions wrong because of precedence problems. So I showed as many ways of structuring the `if`s` as I could think of, without trying to get into which one is better or worse.